# Azure Hybrid Worker Docker

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-automation

I am currently trying to docker-ize a Azure Hybrid Worker using the instructions provided at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-linux-hrw-install

I am 90% successful however when I try to run the final step using onboarding.py the script is not found in the location specificied by the documentation.  Basically the file is not found anywhere in the container.  Any help would be great.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install sudo

ENV user docker

RUN useradd -m -d /home/${user} ${user} && \
    chown -R ${user} /home/${user} && \
    adduser ${user} sudo && \
    echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

USER ${user}

#WORKDIR /home/${user}

RUN sudo apt-get -y install apt-utils && \
 sudo apt-get -y install openssl && \
 sudo apt-get -y install curl && \
 sudo apt-get -y install wget && \
 sudo apt-get -y install cron && \
 sudo apt-get -y install net-tools && \
 sudo apt-get -y install auditd && \
 sudo apt-get -y install python-ctypeslib

RUN sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/master/installer/scripts/onboard_agent.sh && \
sudo sh onboard_agent.sh -w <my-workplace-id> -s <my-workspace-key>

RUN sudo python /opt/microsoft/omsconfig/modules/nxOMSAutomationWorker/DSCResources/MSFT_nxOMSAutomationWorkerResource/automationworker/scripts/onboarding.py --register <arguments-removed-for-stackoverflow-post>

EXPOSE 443
```

Comment: Do you try it in the VM, not in the docker container?

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know the exact reason why it doesn't work yet, I have made some progress that I would like to share.

I've been experimenting with this problem by comparing the differences between centos running on a VM and a centos docker container. Although I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact things that are missing, I was able to get the `onboarding.py` file to show up on a centos docker container.

First what I did is create a file that has a list of packages that are installed on a minimal centos VM. In my docker file I run through this file and install each package. I plan to cut down the file to see what's necessary for this to work.

The second thing is you must have `systemd`, which is not installed by default. Here is what my docker image looks like while I'm testing:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update && yum install -y sudo

RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;


ENV user docker
RUN useradd -m -d /home/${user} ${user}
RUN chown -R ${user} /home/${user}
RUN echo "docker ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER ${user}
WORKDIR /home/${user}

COPY ./install_packages .
RUN sudo yum install -y $(cat ./install_packages)

sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/master/installer/scripts/onboard_agent.sh

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

After that I use `docker run` to run my container locally and start systemd:
`docker run -v /run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -d container_id`

I then `exec` into my container and run the onboard script:

`sudo sh onboard_agent.sh -w 'xxx' -s 'xxx'`

After it's done, you sometimes need to wait about 5 minutes for the missing folders to appear. To trigger this to happen sooner, you need to run this command:

`/opt/microsoft/omsagent/bin/service_control restart {OMS_WORKSTATION_ID}`

My understanding is this command will restart the OMS agent and it requires systemctl.

I understand this doesn't answer your question on how to get it working from building and running the container without having to remote into it. I'm still working on that and I'll let you know if I find an answer.

Good luck.